# Maintain expected json to validate against response payload

Tags: api, rest, automation, assertion

Usecase:
Rest API returns response payload having 10 fields. We have store expected json in DB. When we run test - we compare expected json with actual json returned by api to assert each field.

Let's say - we have 500 such test.

Now - when we change response of Rest API to start returning 15 fields as part of response (additional 5 fields) - for existing 500 tests - should we update expected json to validate additional 5 fields? If yes - what would be most effective way to do it?

Existing approach is - we have to manually update expected json for all 500 tests which is time consuming and can be erroneous.

For Example:

Here is sample response of an API:

{
"field1" : "val1",
"field2" : "val2",
"field3" : {
"field3.a" : "val3",
"field3.b" : "val4",
},
"field4" : "val5"
}

For all 500 tests - we have expected json - with same schema as above to assert all 4 fields.

Now - REST API evolved and started returning 7 fields.

{
"field1" : "val1",
"field2" : "val2",
"field3" : {
"field3.a" : "val3",
"field3.b" : "val4",
},
"field4" : "val5",
"field5" : "val6",
"field6" : "val7",
"field7" : "val8"
}

In such case - existing 500 tests with expected json only assert 5 fields.

To assert all 7 fields - we have to manually update expected json for each 500 tests which is lots of maintenance when rest api response keeps changing.

How to effectively handle it?

Thanks,

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It would be helpful if you could provide some specifics around what language and frameworks (if any) you're using, and also some example code snippets for what you've already tried. This will assist people to provide helpful answers to your question.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Thanks @JaydenMeyer - I have updated question with more detail.